# Invalid Cast Exception on WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync()

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi-direct

I am attempting to create a WifiDirect advertiser in order to pair and connect my PC with an Android phone. Following along with [this Wifi Direct tutorial,](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-98) I have gotten to the point where my PC is advertising a connection, and I can see the option available to connect on the phone. However when I select my computer to connect, the program throws a `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified Cast is not valid.'` error on the `WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsnc()` line.

Below is the relevant `OnConnectionRequested` function which is added as an event listener before publishing begins. I copied the method line for line from the tutorial (15:30), so I am not quite sure where I am going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private async void OnConnectionRequested(WiFiDirectConnectionListener
        sender, WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    WiFiDirectConnectionRequest connectionRequest  = args.GetConnectionRequest();
    //Problem line is here:
    WifiDirectDevice wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(connectionRequest.DeviceInformation.Id);
    var EndpointPairs=wfdDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();
    //TODO establish socket connection using above IP addresses
}

private void StartAdvert ()
{
    publisher = new WiFiDirectAdvertisementPublisher();

    //Sets the listen state to normal, so it can be discovered when app is in foreground
    publisher.Advertisement.ListenStateDiscoverability = WiFiDirectAdvertisementListenStateDiscoverability.Normal;

    listener = new WiFiDirectConnectionListener();
    listener.ConnectionRequested += OnConnectionRequested;
    publisher.Start();
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're doing, but could you change wfdDevice to type object to confirm that's where the invalid cast is? If that's the case, you can check that object to see what type it's returning. That might shed some more light on what's going wrong.

Comment: @cost, the same exception exception is thrown even when wfdDevice is of type object. The docs state `FromIdAsync()` actually returns an `IAsycnOperation`. So I changed it to `FromIdAsync(...).GetResults()`. Unfortunately, I had to remove the await at the beginning on the line, so it threw a null reference in run time.

Comment: If you call FromAsyncID() without assigning the return to anything, you'd still get an invalid cast exception? There's not much else to cast going on in there, I assume the Id in the parameter is valid? Can you post the stacktrace from the exception you're getting?

Comment: The same error is still thrown even when not set to anything. I have been printing the Id to confirm that it exists, and have made sure that it is actually defined as a string.

Comment: Here're the error details: `System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Wifi_Direct_Testing.ConnectToPhone.<OnConnectionRequested>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\hunter\source\repos\Wifi-Direct Testing\Wifi-Direct Testing\ConnectToPhone.xaml.cs:line 60
`

Comment: From [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiDirect/cs/Scenario1_Advertiser.xaml.cs),  it implies the call needs to be executed on UI thread. Please try to see if it is the case.